# Remover caracteres especiales de un string PHP

Tags: php

Necesito almacenar un valor numérico (moneda) en mi bd.
Para ello, desee emplear un método de jQuery llamado `number()` que agrega a los valores sus respectivos signos en su posición, pero necesito quitarle todos esos signos (tanto puntos " **.** " y comas " **,** ") a los valores para no almacenarlos con ellos.

Yo lo estoy intentando con `preg_replace('/,./', '', $valor);`, pero ésto me quita el último dígito del número. Ejm:
Si tengo **120,000** me lo queda así: **12000**

Y aparte de eso, me gustaría convertirlo en un entero antes de almacenarlo, pero con `(int)`120000 me lo deja así: **12**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo revisar que hace el . en las expresiones regulares. Ese es el problema.

**Edit:**

Si pruebas con 120.000, no funciona:

```
$valor = "120.000";
preg_replace("/,./", "", $valor); // "120.000"
```

Esto es porque el . funciona como comodín:

```
preg_replace("/./", "", "123"); // es "" porque busca de izquierda a derecha cualquier caracter y lo reemplaza por nada.
preg_replace("/../", '123'); // es "3" porque busca de izquierda a derecha dos caracteres juntos y los reemplaza por nada.
```

Debes escapar el caracter: `\.`

```
preg_replace("/\./", "",  "12.3"); // "123"
```

Se te puede ocurrir usar dos veces `preg_replace`: uno para la coma y otro para el punto; Sin embargo, hay una manera mejor y es ocupando el operador or: `|`:

```
preg_replace("/a|c/", "",  "abc"); // es "b" porque reemplaza a o c por nada
```

Comment: Pensaría que quitar los puntos ( **.** ) de los números, en caso que vengan con puntos... ( 120.000 )

Comment: Prueba con $valor="120.000" y ve que pasa. El . funciona como comodín, por eso te quita un 0 de más.

Comment: @Aprendiz Lo siento, lo sé.

Comment: Considera editar y agregar un ejemplo para evitar sea marcado tu aporte o re cibas negativos

Comment: En ese sentido, entonces: `preg_replace("/,|./", "",  "120.000,000");` me retornaría: **120000000** ?

Comment: En preg_replace, `/,|./` significa: cuando encuentres de izquierda a derecha una `,` o cualquier caracter reemplazalo por nada. En cambio, `/,|\./` significa: cuando encuentres de izquierda a derecha una `,` o un `.` reemplazalo por nada. En el ultimo caso, sí, retornaría: "120000000".